# How to store / retrieve large amounts of data sets within XPages?

Tags: mysql, xpages, bigdata, mime, non-relational-database

Currently we're working on a solution where we want to track (for analysis) the articles a user clicks on/opens and 'likes' from a given list of articles. Subsequently, the user needs to be able to see and re-click/open the article (searching is not needed) in a section on his/her personal user profile. Somewhere around the 100 new articles are posted every day. The increasing(!) amount of daily visitor (users) lies around the 2000 a day. The articles are currently stored and maintained within a MySQL Db.

We could create a new record in the MySQL Db for every article read / 'liked'. 'Worst case' would this create (2500 * 100 = ) 250000 records a day. That won’t hold long of course… **So how would you store (process) this within XPages, given the scenario?**

*My thoughts after reading [“the article” :) about MIME/Bean’s](http://www.timtripcony.com/blog.nsf/d6plinks/TTRY-8NKTPN): what about keeping 'read articleObjects' in a scope and (periodically) store/save them as MIME on the user profile document? This only creates 100 articleObjects a day (or 36500 a year). In addition, one could come up with a mechanism where articleObjects are shifted from one field to another as time passes by, so the active scope would only contain the 'read articleObjects' from last month or so.*

Comment: MySQL does not have a limit as far as know. A more interesting question is what kind of usability the users will have when clicked more then 1000 articles... Will they have a huge list of these articles in the personal profile?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that this exactly what a *relational* database is for. My first approach would be to have a managed bean (session scope) to read/access user's data in MySQL (JDBC). If you want, you can build an internal cache inside the bean.

For the presented use case, I would not bother with the JDBC datasources in ExtLib. Perhaps even the @Jdbc functions would suffice.

Also, you did not say how you are doing the analysis? If you store the information in Domino, you'll probably have to write an export tool.